# Unit Test A Method According to Model

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on unit testing on my MVC 4 application.And below is one of the method for which i want to do unit testing :-

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ProductViewModel model)
    {
        if (model != null)
        {

            return PartialView("_ProductGrid", SearchProduct(model));
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

I have written the unit test method for that but when i am checking it's code coverage by code coverage option then the else part is showing uncovered.But i am not sure the reason for that.

Can anyone help me out on this ?

Below is the code for my test method :

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void IndexPostTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string searchInDescription = "all";

        ProductController controller = new ProductController();
        ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel
        {
            SearchA = true,
            SearchB= true,
            SearchIC = true,
            Description = searchInDescription
        };

        TestControllerBuilder builder = new TestControllerBuilder();
        builder.InitializeController(controller);

        // Act           
        var result = controller.Index(model) as ActionResult;

        var viewmodel = (ProductViewModel)((ViewResultBase)(result)).Model;

        int matches = _productService.LookupA("", searchInDescription).Count +
                      _productService.LookupB("", searchInDescription).Count +
                      _ProductService.LookupC("", searchInDescription).Count;

        if (result != null && viewmodel != null && result.GetType() == typeof(PartialViewResult))
        {
            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(viewmodel, typeof(ProductViewModel));

            if (viewmodel.Products != null)
                Assert.AreEqual(matches, viewmodel.Products.Count());
            if (matches > 0 && viewmodel.Products != null && viewmodel.Products.ToList().Count > 0 && viewmodel.Products.ToList()[0].Description != "")
            {
                Assert.IsTrue(viewmodel.Products.ToList()[0].Description.ToUpper().Contains(searchInDescription.ToUpper()));
            }
        }
        else if (result != null && result.GetType() == typeof(RedirectResult))
        {
            var redirectResult = result as RedirectResult;
            // Assert
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);
            Assert.AreEqual("Index", redirectResult.Url);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your unit test for else part?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use conditional logic in your tests. Never. Test should return same results when you run it multiple times, and it should verify single thing. So, you actually should have two tests - one which verifies case when model is valid (you have that test), and another one, which verifies case when model is not valid (you don't have that test, because you provide valid model).

First test is for valid model:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldProvideProductGridWhenModelIsNotNull()
{
    // Arrange        
    ProductController controller = new ProductController();
    ProductViewModel model = new ProductViewModel
    {
        SearchA = true,
        SearchB= true,
        SearchIC = true,
        Description = searchInDescription
    };

    // ... other arrange code

    // Act           
    var result = (PartialViewResult)controller.Index(model);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    var viewmodel = (ProductViewModel)result.Model;
    // ... other assertions
}
```

And second test for redirection:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ShouldRedirectToIndexWhenModelIsNull()
{
    // Arrange        
    ProductController controller = new ProductController();      

    // ... other arrange code

    // Act           
    var result = (RedirectToActionResult)controller.Index(null);

    // Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.AreEqual("Index", redirectResult.Url);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're only ever testing the `Index` action with a model which is not null. Therefore the `else` part of the `Index` action will never be called from your test.

You need two tests. One which tests when the model is null and one when it isn't.

```
[TestMethod]
public void IndexPost_NotNull()
{
    // TODO: Setup test data as you have done

    // Act           
    var result = controller.Index(model) as ActionResult;

    // Assert
    // TODO: check result is a partial view result
}

[TestMethod]
public void IndexPost_Null()
{
    // Act           
    var result = controller.Index(null) as ActionResult;

    // Assert
    // TODO: check result is a redirect result
}
```